# javascript break of of loop

Tags: javascript

I know i should know how to do this but some how it escapes me. I need to exit the loop here once I have a match. Why does this not work?

```
ubot.registry.queue.each(function (dj, idx) {
    console.log(idx);
    var user = ubot.registry.users.get(dj.userid);
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(rm_user)
    if(user.name == rm_user) {
        console.log(dj.userid);
        return; // not exiting loop here 
        /*
        if(!ubot.dj_timeout) {
            ubot.remUserFromQueue(user);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log(ubot.dj_timout);
        }
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: what is that each function? how is it defined?

Comment: would someone eplain why the down vote

Comment: We don't know anything about the code you're using, so we don't know what `.each()` method you're using, so we don't know if the API offers a way to break the loop, so we can't directly answer the question. (JavaScript doesn't have a native `.each()`.)

Comment: Are you not going to answer @DanielA.White's question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generic solution since you haven't given us specifics on the code you're running.

It doesn't break the loop. Instead it prevents the code inside the function from running once a flag is set.

```
var flag = false;

ubot.registry.queue.each(function (dj, idx) {
    if( !flag )
        var user = ubot.registry.users.get(dj.userid);
        if(user.name == rm_user) {
            console.log(dj.userid);
            flag = true;
            // rest of the code
        }
    }
});
```

---

> *"Why does this not work?"*

You're returning `undefined`, but functions *always* return `undefined` unless a specific return value is provided. So by doing `return;` you're not doing anything different than the function would do anyway.

Comment: This solves my problem .. in fact putt the return in was causing more problems

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what framework you're using, but I'm going to take a wild guess and suppose that you're using [Prototype's `Enumerable.each`](http://prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each). If so, you can exit the "loop" by using this statement:

```
throw $break;
```

which throws a custom exception that the `each` method understands as meaning "break out of the 'loop'".

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `each()`, then perhaps you have access to `some()` or `any()` or the like -- i.e., a short-circuitable version of `each()`.